# How to retrieve full role hierarchy in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I'm using symfony2 role hierarchy, it works well, but in order to perform some changes, i have to retrieve the `role_hierarchy` set up in my `security.yml`.

```
role_hierarchy:
ROLE_USER: [ROLE_ACCESS_USER, ROLE_ACCESS_DATA, ROLE_ACCESS_PRODUCT]
```

Using `getRoles()` just return `ROLE_USER`, how can i know in my code that `ROLE_USER` is made with `ROLE_ACCESS_USER, ROLE_ACCESS_DATA, ROLE_ACCESS_PRODUCT`?

thanks for helping.

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: my "user" (ROLE_USER) have a default set of roles, i want to permit an admin to give him only specifics roles, e.g only ROLE_ACCESS_DATA. I want to do that via an interface showing all existing roles.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can get the hierarchy from the container:

```
$container->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles')
```

Answer (score 22):

With auto wiring enabled, you can also directly inject the `RoleHierarchy` object filled with the global role hierarchy.
Simply inject the `RoleHierarchyInterface` in your controller or service by using **dependency injection**:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleHierarchyInterface;

public function __construct(RoleHierarchyInterface $roleHierarchy)
{
    $this->roleHierarchy = $roleHierarchy;
}
```

**Note:** This also allows you to call `getReachableRoles()` on the `RoleHierarchy` object, which could be useful in your case:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role;

$this->roleHierarchy->getReachableRoles([new Role('ROLE_USER')]);

$this->roleHierarchy->getReachableRoleNames(['ROLE_USER']); // Symfony 5+
```

---

As of Symfony4 you have to add an alias for `security.role_hierarchy` in your `config/services.yml` by adding the following line:

```
services:
    # creating alias for RoleHierarchyInterface
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleHierarchyInterface: '@security.role_hierarchy'
```

Comment: Using Symfony 3.4 - I had to use an aliast too.

Comment: The alias was added in Symfony 4.1 and does not need to be manually added anymore: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/26639

Comment: How about symfony 5?

Answer (score 8):

## **Symfony 5** answer

```php
namespace App\Controller;

...
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleHierarchyInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleHierarchy;

class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    private $roleHierarchy;

    /**
     * @Route("/users", name="users")
     */
    public function usersIndex(RoleHierarchyInterface $roleHierarchy)
    {
        $this->roleHierarchy = $roleHierarchy;

        // your user service or your Doctrine code here
        $users = ...

        foreach ($users as $user) {
            if ($this->isGranted($user, 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')) {
                ...
            }
        }
        ...
    }

    private function isGranted(User $user, string $role): bool 
    {
        $reachableRoles = $this->roleHierarchy->getReachableRoleNames($user->getRoles());

        foreach ($reachableRoles as $reachableRole) {
            if ($reachableRole === $role) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

*Note: I put everything in the controller for the sake of simplicity here, but of course I'd recommend to move the Role Management code into your own dedicated role service.*

Comment: `$roles = $roleHierarchy->getReachableRoleNames($user->getRoles());` is not used in `usersIndex()` method - is it forgotten statement?

Comment: @long thanks no idea why that ended up here. Fixed :)

Comment: How can you overwrite the `RoleHierarchy` Interface with extended logic without mentioning it in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

For a correct representation of your roles, you need recursion. Roles can extend other roles.

Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36900807/3635680

Comment: Please quote the relevant text in your answer. It's not recommended to post link-only answers (even if the link leads to Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 0):

security.role_hierarchy.roles is all security roles defined in security.yml

If you want to include Sonata Admin roles, you could check code in SonataUserBundle\Form\Type\SecurityRolesType

```
foreach ($this->pool->getAdminServiceIds() as $id) {
            try {
                $admin = $this->pool->getInstance($id);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                continue;
            }

            $securityHandler = $admin->getSecurityHandler();

            foreach ($securityHandler->buildSecurityInformation($admin) as $role => $acls) {
                $roles[$role] = $role;
            }
        }
```