# How can I pass a full security roles list/hierarchy to a FormType class in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a user edit form where I would like to administer the roles assigned to a user.

Currently I have a multi-select list, but I have no way of populating it with the role hierarchy defined in security.yml.

Is there some way that I get this information to the form builder in the FormType class?

```
$builder->add('roles', 'choice', array(
                'required' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'choices' => array(),
            ));
```

Looking around [I found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8931181/461813) that I can get the roles from the container in a controller with:

```
$roles = $this->container->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles');
```

I have also discovered that I could potentially set this as a dependency to be injected on the FormType class in services.xml:

```
<parameters>
    <parameter key="security.role_heirarchy.roles">ROLE_GUEST</parameter>
</parameters>
<services>
    <service id="base.user.form.type.user_form" class="Base\UserBundle\Form\UserType" public="false">
        <tag name="form.type" />
        <call method="setRoles">
            <argument>%security.role_heirarchy.roles%</argument>
        </call>
    </service>
</services>
```

This however does not work and does not seem to ever call the `setRoles` method.

So how can I get this to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your controller

```
$editForm = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $entity, array('roles' => $this->container->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles')));
```

In UserType :

```
$builder->add('roles', 'choice', array(
    'required' => true,
    'multiple' => true,
    'choices' => $this->refactorRoles($options['roles'])
))

[...]

public function getDefaultOptions()
{
    return array(
        'roles' => null
    );
}

private function refactorRoles($originRoles)
{
    $roles = array();
    $rolesAdded = array();

    // Add herited roles
    foreach ($originRoles as $roleParent => $rolesHerit) {
        $tmpRoles = array_values($rolesHerit);
        $rolesAdded = array_merge($rolesAdded, $tmpRoles);
        $roles[$roleParent] = array_combine($tmpRoles, $tmpRoles);
    }
    // Add missing superparent roles
    $rolesParent = array_keys($originRoles);
    foreach ($rolesParent as $roleParent) {
        if (!in_array($roleParent, $rolesAdded)) {
            $roles['-----'][$roleParent] = $roleParent;
        }
    }

    return $roles;
}
```

Comment: `getDefaultOptions` was deprecated in Symfony 2.1 and removed in 2.3. [Use `setDefaultOptions` instead](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.1.md#deprecations).

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own type and then pass service container, from which you can then retrieve role hierarchy.

First, create your own type:

```
class PermissionType extends AbstractType 
{
    private $roles;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->roles = $container->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles');
    }
    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
              'choices' => $this->roles,
        );
    );

    public function getParent(array $options)
    {
        return 'choice';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'permission_choice';
    }
}
```

Then you need to register your type as service and set parameters:

```
services:
      form.type.permission:
          class: MyNamespace\MyBundle\Form\Type\PermissionType
          arguments:
            - "@service_container"
          tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: permission_choice }
```

Then during creation of form, simply add *permission_choice* field:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('roles', 'permission_choice');
}
```

If you want to get only single list of roles without hierarchy, then you need to *flat hierarchy* somehow. One of possible solution is this:

```
class PermissionType extends AbstractType 
{
    private $roles;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $roles = $container->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles');
        $this->roles = $this->flatArray($roles);
    }

    private function flatArray(array $data)
    {
        $result = array();
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if (substr($key, 0, 4) === 'ROLE') {
                $result[$key] = $key;
            }
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $tmpresult = $this->flatArray($value);
                if (count($tmpresult) > 0) {
                    $result = array_merge($result, $tmpresult);
                }
            } else {
                $result[$value] = $value;
            }
        }
        return array_unique($result);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution with $options array provided by webda2l does not work with Symfony 2.3. It gives me an error:

> The option "roles" do not exist.

I found that we can pass parameters to the form type constructor.

In your controller :

```php
$roles_choices = array();

$roles = $this->container->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles');

# set roles array, displaying inherited roles between parentheses
foreach ($roles as $role => $inherited_roles)
{
    foreach ($inherited_roles as $id => $inherited_role)
    {
        if (! array_key_exists($inherited_role, $roles_choices))
        {
            $roles_choices[$inherited_role] = $inherited_role;
        }
    }

    if (! array_key_exists($role, $roles_choices))
    {
        $roles_choices[$role] = $role.' ('.
            implode(', ', $inherited_roles).')';
    }
}

# todo: set $role as the current role of the user

$form = $this->createForm(
    new UserType(array(
        # pass $roles to the constructor
        'roles' => $roles_choices,
        'role' => $role
    )), $user);
```

In UserType.php :

```php
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    private $roles;
    private $role;

    public function __construct($options = array())
    {
        # store roles
        $this->roles = $options['roles'];
        $this->role = $options['role'];
    }
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder,
        array $options)
    {
        // ...
        # use roles
        $builder->add('roles', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => $this->roles,
            'data' => $this->role,
        ));
        // ...
    }
}
```

I took the idea from [Marcello Voc](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/symfony2/z4RvxhuktyE/fNi4yQZHUrUJ), thanks to him!

Answer (score 1):

For to symfony 2.3:

```
<?php

namespace Labone\Bundle\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;

class PermissionType extends AbstractType 
{
    private $roles;

    public function __construct(Container $container)
    {
        $roles = $container->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles');
        $this->roles = $this->flatArray($roles);
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'choices' => $this->roles
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'choice';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'permission_choice';
    }

    private function flatArray(array $data)
    {
        $result = array();
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if (substr($key, 0, 4) === 'ROLE') {
                $result[$key] = $key;
            }
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $tmpresult = $this->flatArray($value);
                if (count($tmpresult) > 0) {
                    $result = array_merge($result, $tmpresult);
                }
            } else {
                $result[$value] = $value;
            }
        }
        return array_unique($result);
    }
}
```