# creating a list of role options for FOSUserBundle registration page

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to implement an answer from the topic as covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517452/how-can-i-pass-a-full-security-roles-list-hierarchy-to-a-formtype-class-in-symfo), but I'm having issues!

**Q**
I am getting the following error when loading the registration form

```
Notice: Undefined index: roles
```

with reference to

```
in src/Ampisoft/Bundle/etrackBundle/Form/Type/RegistrationFormType.php at line 21
```

**RegistrationFormType::RegisterAction**

Ive tested the output of $roles on the 2nd line of this snippet and I have a full array as expected.

```
//.......
$roles = $this->container->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles');
    var_dump($roles);
    return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.'.$this->getEngine(), array(
        'form' => $form->createView(
            array('roles' => $roles,
            )),
    ));
// .......
```

The problem seems to be the way Im passing (or retrieving from) the `$roles` array to the Type class.

**RegistrationFormType**

```
class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $roles;

    public function __construct($options = array())
    {
        $this->roles = $options['roles']; // <--------------- THIS IS line 21
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // custom form fields
        $builder->add('firstname');
        $builder->add('lastname');
        $builder->add('roles', 'choice', array(
            'required' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
            'choices' => $this->refactorRoles($this->roles)
        ));
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions()
    {
        return array(
            'roles' => null
        );
    }

    private function refactorRoles($originRoles)
    {
        $roles = array();
        $rolesAdded = array();

        // Add herited roles
        foreach ($originRoles as $roleParent => $rolesHerit) {
            $tmpRoles = array_values($rolesHerit);
            $rolesAdded = array_merge($rolesAdded, $tmpRoles);
            $roles[$roleParent] = array_combine($tmpRoles, $tmpRoles);
        }
        // Add missing superparent roles
        $rolesParent = array_keys($originRoles);
        foreach ($rolesParent as $roleParent) {
            if (!in_array($roleParent, $rolesAdded)) {
                $roles['-----'][$roleParent] = $roleParent;
            }
        }

        return $roles;
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'fos_user_registration';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'etrack_user_registration';
    }

}
```

I've tried various ways of passing the contents of the `security.hierarchy.roles` array through to the Type class but to no avail.

Comment: How the controller call `RegistrationFormType`?

Comment: that first snippet is the default FOSUserBundle code from the RegistrationController.  Im not sure how it calls it, as its not immediately obvious.  All Ive done is pass an array to it.