# How to inject container in FormType class in Symfony2/3

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony

I am overriding FOSUserBundle group form, and I want to add a select to choose a role form thom available in security.yml.

I would like if possible to avoid to override the controller as well.

so in my FormType I have

```
$roleHierarchy = $this->container->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles');
```

but $this->container is not available. Can I inject it in the controller from service.yml?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass a full security roles list/hierarchy to a FormType class in Symfony2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517452/how-can-i-pass-a-full-security-roles-list-hierarchy-to-a-formtype-class-in-symfo)

Comment: not really, I'd need to do that avoiding to override the controller. thanks.

Comment: Since it is formtype there is no way to that without overriding the controller.