# Symfony2: Getting the list of user roles in FormBuilder

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm making a form for user creation, and I want to give one or several roles to a user when I create him.

How do I get the list of roles defined in `security.yml`?

Here's my form builder at the moment:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

    // add your custom fields
    $user = new User();
    $builder->add('regionUser');
    $builder->add('roles' ,'choice' ,array('choices' => $user->getRolesNames(),
            'required'  => true,
    ));

}
```

and in User.php

```
public function getRolesNames(){
    return array(
        "ADMIN" => "Administrateur",
        "ANIMATOR" => "Animateur",
        "USER" => "Utilisateur",        
    );
}
```

Of course, this solution doesn't work, because `roles` is defined as a bitmap in the database, therefore the `choices` list cannot be created.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think @Mihai Aurelian answer is better suited for your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246774/symfony2-getting-the-list-of-user-roles-in-formbuilder/24926223#24926223

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`security.role_hierarchy.roles` container parameter holds the role hierarchy as an array. You can generalize it to get list of roles defined.

Comment: for those who don't get what it means, use this in your controller:
$roles = $this->get('security.role_hierarchy');

Comment: mine returns empty, when i `var_dump` this it doesn't even echo `null`, any idea why ?

Comment: Not sure when this changed but in 2.5 it's 'security.role_hierarchy'

Comment: @sepehr Well deserved answer.

Answer (score 15):

You can get a list of reachable roles from this method:

```
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleHierarchy::getReachableRoles(array $roles)
```

It seems to return all roles reachable from roles in array `$roles` parameter. It's an internal service of Symfony, whose ID is `security.role_hierarchy` and is not public (you must explicitely pass it as parameters, it's not acessible from Service Container).

Comment: In addition to this good answer I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Glideh/27edd82b6b953b0b431225de9796c697) for a `RolesType` to use directly in a `UserFormType`

Answer (score 10):

For a correct representation of your roles, you need recursion. Roles can extend other roles.

I use for the example the folowing roles in security.yml:

```
ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
ROLE_TEST:        ROLE_USER
```

You can get this roles with:

```
$originalRoles = $this->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles');
```

An example with recursion:

```
private function getRoles($originalRoles)
{
    $roles = array();

    /**
     * Get all unique roles
     */
    foreach ($originalRoles as $originalRole => $inheritedRoles) {
        foreach ($inheritedRoles as $inheritedRole) {
            $roles[$inheritedRole] = array();
        }

        $roles[$originalRole] = array();
    }

    /**
     * Get all inherited roles from the unique roles
     */
    foreach ($roles as $key => $role) {
        $roles[$key] = $this->getInheritedRoles($key, $originalRoles);
    }

    return $roles;
}

private function getInheritedRoles($role, $originalRoles, $roles = array())
{
    /**
     * If the role is not in the originalRoles array,
     * the role inherit no other roles.
     */
    if (!array_key_exists($role, $originalRoles)) {
        return $roles;
    }

    /**
     * Add all inherited roles to the roles array
     */
    foreach ($originalRoles[$role] as $inheritedRole) {
        $roles[$inheritedRole] = $inheritedRole;
    }

    /**
     * Check for each inhered role for other inherited roles
     */
    foreach ($originalRoles[$role] as $inheritedRole) {
        return $this->getInheritedRoles($inheritedRole, $originalRoles, $roles);
    }
}
```

The output:

```
array (
  'ROLE_USER' => array(),
  'ROLE_TEST' => array(
                        'ROLE_USER' => 'ROLE_USER',
  ),
  'ROLE_ADMIN' => array(
                        'ROLE_USER' => 'ROLE_USER',
  ),
  'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN' => array(
                        'ROLE_ADMIN' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
                        'ROLE_USER' => 'ROLE_USER',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Available if `autowire` and `autogofigure` are set to true. I personnaly don't like this at all.. ! If not, set your `RolesType` as before in `services.yml`

Answer (score 9):

You can make a service for this and inject the "security.role_hierarchy.roles" parameter.

Service definition:

```
acme.user.roles:
   class: Acme\DemoBundle\Model\RolesHelper
   arguments: ['%security.role_hierarchy.roles%']
```

Service Class:

```
class RolesHelper
{
    private $rolesHierarchy;

    private $roles;

    public function __construct($rolesHierarchy)
    {
        $this->rolesHierarchy = $rolesHierarchy;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        if($this->roles) {
            return $this->roles;
        }

        $roles = array();
        array_walk_recursive($this->rolesHierarchy, function($val) use (&$roles) {
            $roles[] = $val;
        });

        return $this->roles = array_unique($roles);
    }
}
```

You can get the roles in your controller like this:

```
$roles = $this->get('acme.user.roles')->getRoles();
```

Comment: I would suggest to walk the hierarchy in the constructor to avoid doing it every time `getRoles` is called.

Comment: You are right. Edited the answer to only call array_walk_recursive once.

Comment: You are still doing it every time `getRoles()` is called. Why not do it when the service is initiated?

Comment: Well, when you call getRoles the first time it will save the array in the $roles property. Every other time it will return the roles from this property. In my application, the RolesHelper class also has other methods for other things(it is not used just for this). If I put the array_walk in the constructor, it will be called all the time, even if i don't call getRoles(). Even if you use this class only for the roles list, in the future you may add other methods to it, so it seems more logical to keep the constructor clean.

Answer (score 4):

In Symfony 3.3, you can create a RolesType.php as follows:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleHierarchyInterface;

/**
 * @author Echarbeto
 */
class RolesType extends AbstractType {

  private $roles = [];

  public function __construct(RoleHierarchyInterface $rolehierarchy) {
    $roles = array();
    array_walk_recursive($rolehierarchy, function($val) use (&$roles) {
      $roles[$val] = $val;
    });
    ksort($roles);
    $this->roles = array_unique($roles);
  }

  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'choices' => $this->roles,
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'aria-hidden' => 'true',
            'ref' => 'input',
            'multiple' => '',
            'tabindex' => '-1'
        ),
        'required' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
        'empty_data' => null,
        'label_attr' => array(
            'class' => 'control-label'
        )
    ));
  }

  public function getParent() {
    return ChoiceType::class;
  }

}
```

Then add it to the form as follows:

```
$builder->add('roles', RolesType::class,array(
          'label' => 'Roles'
      ));
```

**Important is that each role must also be contained, for example:
ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER]**

Answer (score 3):

If you need to get all inherited roles of certain role:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleHierarchy;

private function getRoles($role)
{
    $hierarchy = $this->container->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles');
    $roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchy($hierarchy);
    $roles = $roleHierarchy->getReachableRoles([new Role($role)]);
    return array_map(function(Role $role) { return $role->getRole(); }, $roles);
}
```

Then call this functon: `$this->getRoles('ROLE_ADMIN');`

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you want but it makes your example working:

```
use Vendor\myBundle\Entity\User;

public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

    // add your custom fields
    $user = new User();
    $builder->add('regionUser');
    $builder->add('roles' ,'choice' ,array('choices' => User::getRolesNames(),
            'required'  => true,
    ));
}
```

But regarding getting your Roles from an entity, maybe you can use entity repository stuff to query the database.

Here is a good example to get what to want using the **queryBuilder** into the entity repository:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

    // add your custom fields
    $user = new User();
    $builder->add('regionUser');
    $builder->add('roles' ,'entity' array(
                 'class'=>'Vendor\MyBundle\Entity\User',
                 'property'=>'roles',
                 'query_builder' => function (\Vendor\MyBundle\Entity\UserRepository $repository)
                 {
                     return $repository->createQueryBuilder('s')
                            ->add('orderBy', 's.sort_order ASC');
                 }
                )
          );
}
```

http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/symfony2-entity-field-type/

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I can always get roles from the database (and perhaps I will if there is no other way) indeed, but I'm actually aiming at getting the roles I defined in security. Defining them in User was just a way to cope with it, but if you know how to get the roles defined in security, I'll take it!

Comment: Stupid me :) You maybe should use Yaml parser to transform security.yml into an array that you will read.

Answer (score 1):

In Symfony 2.7, in controllers you have to use $this->getParameters() to get roles :

```
$roles = array();
foreach ($this->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles') as $key => $value) {
    $roles[] = $key;

    foreach ($value as $value2) {
        $roles[] = $value2;
    }
}
$roles = array_unique($roles);
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's what I've done:

FormType:

```
use FTW\GuildBundle\Entity\User;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('username')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('enabled', null, array('required' => false))
        ->add('roles', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => User::getRoleNames(),
        'required' => false,'label'=>'Roles','multiple'=>true
    ))
        ->add('disableNotificationEmails', null, array('required' => false));
}
```

In the entity:

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser; ...

static function getRoleNames()
{
    $pathToSecurity = __DIR__ . '/../../../..' . '/app/config/security.yml';
    $yaml = new Parser();
    $rolesArray = $yaml->parse(file_get_contents($pathToSecurity));
    $arrayKeys = array();
    foreach ($rolesArray['security']['role_hierarchy'] as $key => $value)
    {
        //never allow assigning super admin
        if ($key != 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')
            $arrayKeys[$key] = User::convertRoleToLabel($key);
        //skip values that are arrays --- roles with multiple sub-roles
        if (!is_array($value))
            if ($value != 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')
                $arrayKeys[$value] = User::convertRoleToLabel($value);
    }
    //sort for display purposes
    asort($arrayKeys);
    return $arrayKeys;
}

static private function convertRoleToLabel($role)
{
    $roleDisplay = str_replace('ROLE_', '', $role);
    $roleDisplay = str_replace('_', ' ', $roleDisplay);
    return ucwords(strtolower($roleDisplay));
}
```

Please do provide feedback... I've used some suggestions from other answers, but I still feel like this is not the best solution!

Answer (score -3):

```
//FormType
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser;

function getRolesNames(){
        $pathToSecurity = /var/mydirectory/app/config/security.yml
        $yaml = new Parser();
        $rolesArray = $yaml->parse(file_get_contents($pathToSecurity ));

        return $rolesArray['security']['role_hierarchy']['ROLE_USER'];
}
```

This is so far the best way i found to get or set what i want from config files.

Bon courage

Comment: I don't fully agree with this suggestion... but also wanted to improve this cuz hard coding the file path bugs me.
`$pathToSecurity = __DIR__ . '/../../../..' . '/app/config/security.yml';`
`

Comment: would be the same as using a global variable which hasn't a good oo taste..it's always better to inject such things with the container (container parameter security.role_hierarchy.roles)