# Add Role List to FOS Userbundle Profile Edit Form

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

This question is similar to [Symfony2: Getting the list of user roles in FormBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246774/symfony2-getting-the-list-of-user-roles-in-formbuilder) but the answers there are geared towards any form but my question is specific to a form created by the User Bundle. Problem is that the UserBundle Controller creates the form like this:

```
$form = $this->container->get('fos_user.profile.form');
```

Because of this I don't know how to send roles to my Form Type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is similar to the one by @Mihai Aurelian answered on the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246774/symfony2-getting-the-list-of-user-roles-in-formbuilder#answer-24926223).

Created a service called Role Helper:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Services;

/**
 * Roles helper displays roles set in config.
 */
class RolesHelper
{
  private $rolesHierarchy;

  public function __construct($rolesHierarchy)
  {
    $this->rolesHierarchy = $rolesHierarchy;
  }

  /**
   * Return roles.
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function getRoles()
  {
    $roles = array();

    array_walk_recursive($this->rolesHierarchy, function($val) use (&$roles) {
      $roles[] = $val;
    });

    return array_unique($roles);
  }
}
```

Overwrote the Form Type using [Overriding Default FOSUserBundle Forms](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md) instructions and updated the default constructer to include the RolesHelper as an argument.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;
use AppBundle\Services\RolesHelper;

class UserType extends BaseType
{
  /**
   * @var RolesHelper
   */
  private $roles;

  /**
   * @param string $class The User class name
   * @param RolesHelper $roles Array or roles.
   */
  public function __construct($class, RolesHelper $roles)
  {
    parent::__construct($class);

    $this->roles = $roles;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

    $builder->add('firstName')
            ->add('lastName')
            ->add('roles', 'choice', array(
              'choices' => $this->roles->getRoles(),
              'required' => false,
              'multiple'=>true
            ));
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getName()
  {
    return 'user_registration';
  }
}
```

Updated services.yml

```
app_roles_helper:
   class: AppBundle\Services\RolesHelper
   arguments: ['%security.role_hierarchy.roles%']
```

Added second argument to app_user.registration.form.type in services.yml:

```
app_user.registration.form.type:
  class: AppBundle\Form\Type\UserType
  arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%, @app_roles_helper]
  tags:
    - { name: form.type, alias: user_registration }
```

Answer (score 0):

I  can't comment, so I'll make my comment as an answer. The way you wrote your getRoles function it will only return the array position as the roles, something like, if you have a three positions array it will return 0,1,2 as choices, instead of the roles names. Then I tried something different in this line, instead of:

```
array_walk_recursive($this->rolesHierarchy, function($val) use (&$roles) {
  $roles[] = $val;
});
```

I put

```
array_walk_recursive($this->rolesHierarchy, function($val) use (&$roles) {
  $roles[$val] = $val;
});
```

This solved the problem of returning the numerical array positions instead of the roles names. But there was a problem, for a hierarchy like this:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_TEST ]
```

It would only return ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_TEST, but for Symfony, ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN are roles too. The problem resides in the fact that array_walk_recursive will not pass to the callback function a key that it's value is an array. As ROLE_ADMIN is ARRAY(1) => ([0] => (string)ROLE_USER) and ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN is ARRAY(2) => ([0]=>(string)ROLE_ADMIN [1]=>(string)ROLE_TEST), both of them will be ignored.

The solution was to do this:

```
public function getRoles() {
    $roles = array();

    foreach (array_keys($this->rolesHierarchy) as $key){
        $roles[$key] = $key;
        array_walk_recursive($this->rolesHierarchy[$key], function($val) use (&$roles){
            $roles[$val] = $val;
        });
    }

    return array_unique($roles);
```

The array keys are considered, themselves,  roles too, that's the reason to include $roles[$key] = $key. And, to recurse into each of the arrays contained in the hierarchy:

```
        array_walk_recursive($this->rolesHierarchy[$key], function($val) use (&$roles){
            $roles[$val] = $val;
        });
```