# Symfony 2 Access entity data for formtype

Tags: php, symfony

I am making my own login application with Symfony2 and I am new at Symfony. I know that I have the [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) at my disposal, but I'm trying to learn security on my own first.

My access control defines 3 role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER. In addition the defined roles have other roles associated with them, such as ROLE_ADMIN_VIEW_USERS

I am **NOT** using the [security.context service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246774/symfony2-getting-the-list-of-user-roles-in-formbuilder) on entity.roles to map my roles from the entity because I only want to effect ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER. Upon registration every user is given the role ROLE_USER. When a user with ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN views edit page for a user or admin I am trying to put in a checkbox that says 'Make this User an Admin'. If they already have ROLE_ADMIN in the entity getRoles, the box would be checked.

If the box is checked I do this in the action

```
    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
            $role = ( 'ROLE_ADMIN' === $editForm->get('role')->getViewData())
                    ? "ROLE_ADMIN"
                    : "ROLE_USER";
            $entity->setRoles(array($role));
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_new_edit', array('id' => $id)));
        }
```

So my question is: *How do I check the box if in the entity getRoles() is ROLE_ADMIN?* Remember as stated above roles is mapped in the entity, but role is not. I don't want to use roles from the mapped entity because there are several values from the security service that I don't want to use.

```
    $builder
        ->add('username', 'text')
        ->add('password', 'password')
        ->add('email', 'email')
        ->add('role', 'choice', array(
            'mapped' => false,
            'label' => 'Make Admin',
            'value' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
            'required' => false,
            //show following attribute only if entity getRoles is ROLE_ADMIN
            //how do i get the value from the entity?
            'attr' => array('checked'=>'checked'),
            ))
```

Comment: So the problem you have then is determining if the currently edit viewable `User` entity has the `ROLE_ADMIN` set (using `User.getRoles()`), so the checkbox is defaulted to checked or not checked?

Comment: yes @JaredFarrish that is correct.

Comment: And the problem is `User.getRoles()` will give you something like `{"roles":["ROLE_USER","ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN","ROLE_ADMIN "]}` in return? So the raw return of `getRoles()` isn't telling you if `ROLE_ADMIN` is set because it's actually giving you a JSON string of all roles? Why don't you add a `User.isAdmin()` method that gives you that information by getting the data from `User.getRoles()`, reading it, and checking for the `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` or `ROLE_ADMIN` roles in the list?

Comment: Actually @JaredFarrish that is an excelent observation, and that is something that I have already taken care of on submission of the create form. The getRoles will show either one of my three roles, but not all of them. I plan to **not** make the form editable at all for other super admins and have me be the one to set up who the superadmins are as there would only be 1 or 2. Trying to conform to best practices and not use in_memory for super admin, which btw could help with my problem. Don't want to add isAdmin to Entity because I use the entity for several forms.

Comment: When you say you don't want to add `isAdmin` to Entity, what is the entity you're referring? `User`?

Comment: Yes that's correct. And I found my answer...$entity = $builder->getData();
        $role = $entity->getRoles();
        $options = array(
                'mapped' => false,
                'label' => 'Make Admin');
        if( in_array("ROLE_ADMIN", $role)) {
            $options['data'] = true;
        } $builder->add->('role', 'checkbox', $options);

Comment: it may work, but correct way is to use form events, as LorenzSchaef have already mentioned

Comment: @Ziumin - You're saying to move the `if()...` part in the comment above to an event listener, instead of doing it inline in the `FormType::buildForm()` method? (And do this for organizational purposes?)

Comment: @JaredFarrish Hey, after revisiting your comments about adding isAdmin getter/setters to my entity I discovered that you had the right solution all along. If you would please state that comment in an answer I'd love to give you credit for it. And thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be something like this:

```
->add('role', 'choice', array(
            'mapped' => true,
            'label' => 'Make Admin',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'choices' => array('ROLE_ADMIN' => 'Yes')
            'required' => false,
            ))
```

The value should automatically be taken from the entity if it has a property called "roles", just like for your other fields. You can also add other roles to the choices array and you will get a checkbox for each of them.

I didn't test it however, I hope it works.

Comment: **role** is not mapped in the database, **roles** is mapped. In addtition it is mapped with json_array for the security layer. I can't use roles because the mapped roles list is much larger then what I want. In the formtype I want to get the value stored in the database/entity under getRoles and check the box if the return from getRoles is ROLE_ADMIN

Comment: Ok, I see. Maybe this article can help you: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-underlying-data