# How to get all Roles from which a specified Role can be reached hierarchically?

Tags: symfony

My use case is basically that I want to retrieve all users that have a specific role.

That means I also want to retrieve those users who have this role implicitly by having a "stronger" role as defined in my role-hierarchy.

But the `RoleHierarchyInterface` does only provide `getReachableRoleNames`.

Does someone have a solution to this that is better than "fetch all Users, calculate all reachable roles for them and then pick the ones that have the specified one"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One question here is, how are your user's roles stored in database?

Assuming that you use Doctrine, let's take the most simple example: your users have a "role" property that contains a single "root" role which is saved as a string in database.

### First step

I think that in both cases, the first step would be to determine the list of roles from which the target role can be reached.

If performance is not an issue, a "simple" solution would be:

- Get a list of all the roles ([Symfony2: Getting the list of user roles in FormBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246774/symfony2-getting-the-list-of-user-roles-in-formbuilder) can help with that).
- Loop through them calling `getReachableRoleNames` and keep only those for which it includes the target role.

This can be improved in terms of performance:

- We run a first recursive algorithm to list all roles, and then we check the hierarchy for each, but a single recursive algorithm could go through the hierarchy and get the list we want directly.
- If you really have a lot of roles, you could also cache the result in the Symfony cache (the role hierarchy itself is stored in cache too iirc).

### Second step

The list of roles we got from the first step (let's call it `$targetRoles`) is the list of roles for which any user having one of these roles will also have the target roles through the hierarchy. Now the solution will depend on how user roles are stored in database.

In our "simple" example:

```php
$queryBuilder = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->createQueryBuilder('u');
$queryBuilder
  ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->in('u.role', $targetRoles))
  ->getQuery()
  ->getResult()
;
```

Comment: Thanks! I got things to work with an approach that widely works like you described so i'm accepting this as answer. Luckily all my roles are stored in an enum so i don't have to retrieve them through the container. The storage of roles within the DB is a bit more complex but getting this last step to work was more an SQL-query-crafting-task than anything else. I was also thinking of building some form of graph-structure of the roles that could be cached and queried. But i kinda hoped there would be a "batteries-included"-solution out there. I feel like this should be part of the API...